# Using Extension in ASP.NET application - .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, nest, .net-6.0

I'm trying to get NEST working in an ASP.NET application. I'm following the guide https://blexin.com/en/blog-en/how-to-integrate-elasticsearch-in-asp-net-core/#highlighter_541789. I'm trying to figure out how to call `AddElasticsearch` correctly on the builder. I've tried a few ways but keep getting compiler complaints.

`Extensions.cs`

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void AddElasticsearch(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var url = configuration["elasticsearch:url"];
        var defaultIndex = configuration["elasticsearch:index"];

        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(url)).DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

        AddDefaultMappings(settings);

        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        services.AddSingleton(client);

        CreateIndex<LegiscanModelBill>(client, defaultIndex);
    }

    private static void AddDefaultMappings(ConnectionSettings settings) => settings.DefaultMappingFor<LegiscanModelBill>(m => m);

    // private static void CreateIndex<T>(IElasticClient client, string indexName)
    // {
    //     var createIndexResponse = client.Indices.Create(indexName,
    //         index => index.Map<LegiscanModelBill>(x => x.AutoMap())
    //     );
    // }

    private static void CreateIndex<T>(ElasticClient client, string indexName) where T : class
    {
        client.Indices.Create($"{indexName}_{typeof(T).ToString}", i => i.Map<T>(m => m.AutoMap()));
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services
    .AddElasticsearch(options => options.configuration)
    .AddGraphQLServer()
    .AddQueryType<Query>();


var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGraphQL();

app.Run();
```

`compiler error`

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IConfiguration' because it is not a delegate type
```

Comment: `options => options.configuration` what makes you think this is correct? Where did you get this from?

Comment: It's been a while since I've done .NET so I'm really just guessing. That is an option that the VSCode suggested. @nvoigt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `options => options.configuration` which is just a random guess with no meaning, use `builder.Configuration`.

To be honest, I think that this new way of having a `main` method and not actually having a main method is hiding so much that it doesn't make it "easier", it actually makes it *harder* to understand what is actually happening. Because it's all hidden. Anyway, that is what you need to do.

Comment: I've tried that already but I get the error `'WebApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddElasticsearch' and the best extension method overload 'Extensions.AddElasticsearch(IServiceCollection, IConfiguration)' requires a receiver of type 'IServiceCollection'`

Comment: Was able to get it working by changing the Extension definition `public static void AddElasticsearch(this WebApplicationBuilder builder, IConfiguration configuration)` and updating the code to use `builder.Services`

Comment: To the original comment, it's no less obscure and infact, you can use intellisense to see find the equivalent properties.

@AntarrByrd add the extensions on IServiceCollection and then add the appropriate using.